# Value from dropdown menu is not received when the option has been chosen

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

The program starts with:

```
session_start();
$seq = 0;
if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {   
    echo $_POST['fname']."<br/>";
    if (isset($_POST['uid']) {
        echo $_POST['uid']."<br/>";
        if ($_POST['submit'] && $_POST['edupdel'] != "ABCD") {
            echo "postsubmit  = ".$_POST['submit']."<br/>";
            echo "edupdel = ".$_POST['edupdel']."<br/>";
            echo "past submit<br/>";

            $opt = $_REQUEST['edupdel'];
            echo "OPTION IS  = ".$opt;
        }   
    }   
}   
$fname  = $_POST['fname'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$opt = $_POST['edupdel'];

echo $uid.$fname.$opt."<br/>";
echo "*******<br/>";
$seq = $seq + 1 ;
echo "SEQ # is = ".$seq."<br/>";
```

The idea being:  uid and fname are being carried over since the first page and work OK. I can get those values correctly.
The program uses: `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">`

(GET or REQUEST were options  considered but so far no success).
The program has a drop down menu. The first entry "ABCD" id just dummy for now and should not be used in the future.

```
Please select one of the options:
<select name="edupdel">
    <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>
    <option value="edit">EDIT</option>
    <option value="update">UPDATE</option>
    <option value="delete">DELETE</option>
</select>
```

The submit goes like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" >
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $_POST['uid']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="edupdel" value="<?php echo $_POST['edupdel']; ?>">
```

Now, from the top of my ignorance, I don't know how to retrieve the value for the:`<select name="edupdel">`

This is not shown when I select, for example, the option EDIT from the menu.  I'm not even sure that this is the correct way to obtain the value selected from the drop down list.

So what do I expect: Have uid, fname and the selected option set so I can decide the next step.
Please bear in mind that I'm starting with PHP and the whole shebang, so at this point, after looking in the forum for hours, I decided to take a shot and ask the forum guys what would be the best way to code what I need or just plain point me to some other possible options.

```
Some debugging data I could get to so far according to the "echos"  above:
mary
john 
postsubmit = Submit
edupdel =
past submit
OPTION IS = johnmary ( I would expect EDIT or UPDATE or DELETE after the word mary)
*******
SEQ # is = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a hidden input field after the submit button with the name `edupdel`.  If this is the case, anything in that input's value will override anything selected in the `<select>` field.

Try either removing that hidden field, or moving it above the `<select>` field in the HTML so the select takes precedence.